# SqlDbType and Geography

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ado.net

What SqlDbType enumeration should I use when my column is the Geography type? I'm using MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

This is what I'm looking for specifically:

```
// ADO.net - what do I use for the SqlDbType when it's defined 
// as Geography in the stored proc
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandText = "dbo.up_Foobar_Insert";
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

command.Parameters.Add("@SomeGeographyType", SqlDbType.????);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Try this:

```
//define parameter
command.Parameters.Add("@shape", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
//
//code in between omitted
//
//set value of parameter
command.Parameters["@shape"].Value = feature.Geometry.AsText();
```

Taken from [Inserting SQL 2008 Geometry With a SqlCommand](http://geobabble.wordpress.com/2007/12/18/inserting-sql-2008-geometry-with-a-sqlcommand/)

Answer (score 13):

`SqlGeography` is implemented as a CLR user defined type by SQL Server, so you can do something a little like:

```
SqlGeography geo = // Get the geography from somewhere...

using (SqlCommand command = 
    new SqlCommand(@"dbo.up_Foobar_Insert", connection))
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Point", geo) { UdtTypeName = "Geography" });
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

If it is a desktop application you've got it quite a bit easier. There is a good example at the [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sqlgeometry.aspx) of an SQL Geometry viewer that will help for both desktop or web.

You need to reference Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll, found at SQL Server Install/100/SDK/Assemblies to use SQLGeometry or SQLGeography directly.

Comment: There's also a NuGet package with the required assembly: [Microsoft.SqlServer.Types (Spatial)](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/)

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to use `SqlDbType.NVarChar` I received and error

> Failed to convert parameter value from Geography to a String

What resolved this problem for me was to use `SqlDbType.Udt`

```
var pgeo = cmd.Parameters.Add("@GeoLocation", SqlDbType.Udt);
pgeo.UdtTypeName = "Geography";
```

And then later, in a loop, I set the value of the parameter:

```
var ss = new SqlString(objValue.ToString());
var sc = new SqlChars(ss);
var geocode = SqlGeography.STPointFromText(sc, 4326);
cmd.Parameters["@GeoLocation"].Value = geocode;
```

Note:  this requires `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` and `System.Data.SqlTypes`