# Geography not saving in binary

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I'm using the following query in ASP.net to save coordinates in MS SQL:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
    ("Insert Into Properties (nPropertyId, vcCompleteAddress, vcPostCode,
      vcAddressLine1, vcAddressLine2, vcCity, vcCountry, dLatitude,
      dLongitude, gCoordinates, dtmDateAdded, vcUserName, nPropertyTypeId, imgImage
    ) Values(
      @nPropertyId, @vcCompleteAddress, @vcPostCode, @vcAddressLine1,
      @vcAddressLine2, @vcCity, @vcCountry, @dLatitude, @dLongitude,
     geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(" + txtLongitude.Text + " " + txtLatitude.Text + ")', 4326)**, 
      @dtmDateAdded, @vcUserName, @nPropertyTypeId, @imgImage)", conn);
```

However, the geography data is saved as: **POINT (-2.270959 52.2323256)** instead of binary. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

When I try to pass it as parameter with the code below I get the error that I need to convert string to IEnumerable.

```
SqlParameter param12 = new SqlParameter("@gCoordinates", SqlDbType.Udt);
param12.UdtTypeName = "geography";
param12.Value = txtLongitude.Text + " " + txtLatitude.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param12);
param12.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
```

Comment: Why not pass it as a [parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3966372/15498) like the rest of your values?

Comment: What do you mean the data is saved? If the column is geography data type then it will only accept a geography. Do you get an error? If so, what is it. Also, I guess you added those two asterisks - they're not actually in the insert command are they?

Comment: When I try to pass it as parameter with the code below I get the error that I need to convert string to IEnumerable.

//            SqlParameter param12 = new SqlParameter("@gCoordinates", SqlDbType.Udt);
//            param12.UdtTypeName = "geography";
//            param12.Value = txtLongitude.Text + " " + txtLatitude.Text;
//            cmd.Parameters.Add(param12);
//            param12.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;

Comment: I don't get any error. It just saves POINT (-2.270959 52.2323256) in the geography column. I've checked and the syntax is fine.

Comment: If you want to show code, please *[edit]* your question (and use the `{}` button on the code block) - code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: Sorry about that.. I've added the code to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saved the latitude and longitude as long data type instead of geography. It made things simpler and everything is working perfect.