# Save geography type to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

My table has column with 'geography' type. How I can save data to this table with C# `SqlGeography.Point()` and ado.net? I have following code

```
var stringPos = item.Position.Split(',');
var latPos = double.Parse(stringPos[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var longPos = double.Parse(stringPos[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var position = SqlGeography.Point(latPos, longPos, 4326);

string query = @"INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (@position, @postCode)";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@position", position);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postCode", item.ZipCode);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I have following code but it throws exception:

> UdtTypeName property must be set for UDT parameters.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: I'd have thought that the error makes it clear, but if not [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3966372/15498) found by searching on `ado.net geography parameter` seems to have you covered.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever adding UdtTypeName = "Geography" helps, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

Change

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@position", position);
```

To

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@position", position) { UdtTypeName = "Geography" });
```