# How I can send null values in Geography SQL Server field if allow NULL, with SqlParameter and SQL Server Types SqlGeography in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, null, sqlparameter

According to the following solution
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/42976399/2825284):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@position", position) { UdtTypeName = "Geography" });
```

My code:

```
SqlGeography geographyfield = null;
sqlParameter.ParameterName = "@geographyfield";
sqlParameter.UdtTypeName = "Geography";

if (geographyfield != null)
    sqlParameter.Value = geographyfield;
else
    sqlParameter.Value = DBNull.Value; // or null, I get the same error
```

How I can send null values in Geography field if allow NULL?

I get this error:

> UdtTypeName property must be set only for UDT parameters.

Comment: [`SqlGeography.Null`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.null).

Comment: Thanks, I see the answer was obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According Jeroen Mostert's comment this is the solution: `SqlGeography.Null`.

```
SqlGeography geographyfield = null;
sqlParameter.ParameterName = "@geographyfield";
sqlParameter.UdtTypeName = "Geography";

if (geographyfield != null)
    sqlParameter.Value = geographyfield;
else
    sqlParameter.Value = SqlGeography.Null;
```

Thanks Jeroen Mostert.

Comment: This can be written more succinctly as `sqlParameter.Value = geographyfield ?? SqlGeography.Null`.

Answer (score 0):

One option can be set data has min value or another unexpected value that you can take like a null or unset value. Is in sql value set this field has nullable?

Comment: Yes, with Jeroen Mostert's comment is the solution: SqlGeography.Null. Thanks.